# Does the Delphi compiler compile the attributes?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Why Delphi(XE5) compiler will not get any errors when everything as attribute that is on top of property?

```
  TPerson = class
  private
    FID: integer;
  public
    [XYZ]
    property ID: integer read FID write FID;
  end;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you enable compiler warnings the following warning is emitted:

> [dcc32 Warning]: W1025 Unsupported language feature: 'custom attribute'

If you specify in your project settings that `W1025` should be treated as an error, then the compiler will indeed report this an an error.

Note that [Stefan Glienke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/587106/stefan-glienke) has submitted a [QP report, RSP-20384](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20384), relating to the misleading nature of this warning.